# How to create a synchronous function from an asynchronous one for backwards compatability

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

> Disclaimer: I know that synchro stuff is to be avoided, and that promises and callbacks are preferrable, but I'm stuck writing a system that needs a small amount of backwards compatability, and need to write this for a temporary stop gap.

Writing an express.js app, I have a function that takes the request object from a .get or .post etc function, and confirms whether the session key is valid (after checking this with a remote API server).  The main version of the function is like this:

```
module.exports.isValidSession(req, cb) {
    // REST API Calls and callbacks, error handling etc, all works fine.
}
```

I need a version of the above to be compatible with an older system (that will soon be phased out).  I'm quite new to Node, although not to JS, so I'm wondering if there's a good convention on how to do this?

**Additional Info**

The main problem I hit is returning a synchronous function from some kind of 'watcher' - See below for one approach I considered, which doesn't work, but I figure maybe someone knows an approach to.  (It's essentialy polling the value of a variable until the async function sets it to indicate it's done.)

```
function isValidSession(req) {

    var running = 1, ret = -1;

    var looper = setInterval(function () {

        if (!running) {
            clearInterval(looper);
            return ret; // This is the problem bit.  Returns an async interval function, not the parent.
        }

    }, 500);

    request(requestOpts, function (error, response, body) {

        if (error) {
            ret = new Error('Some error went on');
            running = -1;
        }

        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            ret = true;
            running = -1;
        }

    });

}
```

Might well not be possible, or more likely, not viable, but it'd be really useful if I could include this for backwards compat for a week or so.  It's a dev project atm, so if it's not good practice, it'll do as long as it doesn't comprimise everything.  I do realise, though, that it basically goes against the whole point of Node (although Node itself includes several functions that are available in both sync and async versions).

All help gratefully received.

Comment: so you want a version that just returns a `boolean` instead of invoking the callback?

Comment: @Alnitak, essentially, yes.  It needs to make the request, and on return or timeout, return a boolean value accordingly.  The main problem I'm hitting is returning the function, as all methods I can come up with (Intervals to check value of a variable that is changed by the callback for instance) return their own function, but not the parent function.

Comment: @vkurchatkin, Maybe not, but Node.js does include functions like this, like fs.read and fs.readSync.  I realise these are done natively, but I'm hoping there's a way for me to do it.

Comment: sorry, you can't, unless the underlying async call provides an option to make the call synchronous.

Comment: I'm suspecting that you're both right.  I've added a bit of example code for an approach I considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Lets pretend there is a strong reason why author desires this.*

There is a rather popular (so, you are not alone) module called [synchronize.js](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html)

Use case:

1. Add callback to your `isValidSession`

   ```
   function isValidSession(req, cb) {

   request(requestOpts, function (error, response, body) {

       if (error) {
           cb(new Error('Some error went on'));
       }

       if (response.statusCode === 200) {
           cb(null, true);
       }
   });

   }
   ```
2. Use it with `sync` module:

   `var ret = sync.await(isValidSession(req, sync.defer()))`

P.S. Might require testing, refer to the [documentation](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, was actually in the process of writing my own answer along these lines, but have an upvote.  I won't pretend for a minute that my reasoning for wanting this is particularly valid, and it's certainly not something that's going out in a production site!

Comment: it requires that all your code runs inside of a fiber